# Given two unit vectors what can we say about the rotations that can transform one into another?

Tags: matrices, rotations

Given 2 unit vectors in 2 dimensions there is a uniqe rotation matrix that transforms on to the other. $A$ and $B$ are the two unit vectors is there a general way to find the set of orthogonal rotation matrices that rotate $A$ to $B$?

Comment: How is $A_nB_m$ defined in your formula?

Comment: multiplication of components.

Comment: Could you include an example, say in dimension 2 or 3? Thanks.

Comment: @coffeemath. You are right that matrix is not orthogonal. I changed it.

Comment: It's a coset of a conjugate of $SO(n-1)$ in $SO(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a geometric procedure

We will work on the surface of the unit sphere.  The 2 unit vectors given are points  p,q  fixed on this sphere.
Now take any other  (variable) point  x on this surface. These 3 points (not being collinear) lead to a unique circle C passing through them. That circle will lie on  this surface, call its centre  (not on the surface) O.

Now consider the diameter L  of the sphere passing through O.  Using L as axis there is a unique rotation sending p to q.

Now the third point x was arbitrary;varying it gives different choice of circle C and different diametric line  L and a different rotation. sending p to q.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta &-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta \end{bmatrix}$ is the standard rotation matrix.

What is $\theta$?

$a\cdot b = \cos\theta$ (if $a,b$ are unit vectors)

But what direction?

$a_1b_2 - a_2b_1 > 0$  then $b$ is counter-clockwise from $a$
And if it is less than 0, then $b$ is clockwise from $a.$

You might think of the cross product,  make these into 3 dimensional vectors with $\bf k$ term $0$ for both vectors, $a_1b_2 - a_2b_1$ will be the $\bf k$ term in the cross product.